# Write FTP client with Java 6

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, network-programming, tcp

I want to write a small project for myself - FTP client.
I know to work with GUI, Socket & ServerSocket for TCP communication.
I ask you to tell me what I need more to know for implemening FTP client...
Thanks

Comment: How much do you want to do yourself=

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to read the RFC. After implementing the most common operations, test your client with at least one good FTP servers. There are a few things in the spec that are easy to get wrong. Then, compare what you wrote with other implementations. Some time ago, I wrote an [FTP client for my H2 Database project](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/dev/ftp/FtpClient.java).

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair amount built into standard Java (note, not JAVA, it's not an acronym).

It could be this simple

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    // ....

        try {
            URL url = new URL("ftp://user:pwd@ftp.example.com/test.txt;type=i");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

            // ... do something useful
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report the error
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know that some libraries exist, i.e. [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).
Apart from that you might want to look at [NIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) for some novel approach to network communication. Not saying anything about character encodings (for ASCII transfer you might need it), called [Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) incorrectly.